# Node error on aws ubuntu but not OSX

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, express, error-handling

I have a project written using Express/Node and it runs locally on OSX just fine. However, when I cloned it to an aws EC2 instance running Ubuntu, I get this error:

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT

When I open the public DNS in a browser. The html is served, but nothing in my public directory is being served with it. Even when I go to the files directly (e.g. ./css/style.css).

It must be a difference between Node on Ubuntu and Node on OSX? The error message isn't detailed enough to know what's going wrong...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I should also note that running simple-server on the public folder serves the contents perfectly fine.

Comment: What command are you running on the server and on OSX? Perhaps you are running your command with different working directories.

Comment: I'm starting the server using the start script ./bin/www that is created with the express generator. The code in the script is just this:
var debug = require('debug')('cog_study');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days, I finally found it. The express generator set up the project with a sass compiler, which requires Ruby and the Sass gem, which the aws Ubuntu distro didn't have. Thanks for helping me with this, everyone. I wish the error messages in node were a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

run the command 
npm rebuild at the Ubuntu server.
This is probably caused by the binary files used in OSX. They're different at Ubuntu.

Comment: It didn't solve the error, but thank you for the tip.

Comment: you are using Ubuntu 14.04?
maybe this can help you:
https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/708 (check soyuka's answer)

Comment: I just created a new EC2 instance and tried what soyuka suggested. I'm still having the issue, though.